# Мне нужен исходный код shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks и dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Использую библиотеку dlib на Питоне 3 и мне нужен исходный код этих сверточных нейросетей. Просто хочу их обучить на других моделях или подскажите как это можно сделать. Заранее спасибо.(я ламер)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то для того, что-бы обучит нейронную сеть вам ее  исходный код не нужен.
Поэтому рекомендую начать не с "хочу обучить", а с того, что-бы разобраться, что такое нейронная сеть на самом деле и как с ней работать. Иначе даже не понятно, что-же вам подсказать.